# How to deserialize a JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am attempt to use an API that use the follow example structure for their returned json:

```json
[{
    "name":"Firs",
    "id":"0",
    "data": {"scale":"1","size":"500"}
},
{
    "name":"Second",
    "id":"1",
    "data":"222"
}]
```

**Upade** "[ ]"

But I can not figure out how to get it to be happy with the provided structure.

Using Newtonsoft I am able to Serialize and Deserialize a model shown below:

```
List<RequestJson> requestJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RequestJson>>(json);
```

```
public class GetData
{
    public int Scale { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public class RequestJson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Problem is here
    public GetData Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that JSON is not valid - there should be a single root element; I would expect it to have a surrounding pair of `[` and `]` - to denote an array; does it not? then you would get a `List<RequestJson>`. However, the data is also heterogeneous - the `data` in the first element is a different shape to the `data` in the second element; this complicates things a lot!

Comment: How are you planning to use the parsed data? I assume you want to handle differently those `RequestJson` objects where the `data` is a string and where `data` is an `GetData` object. If so, having a single data model for both cases might not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. The `Data` property does not match the object type.

Correct JSON:

```
[{
     "name":"Firs",
     "id":"0",
     "data": {"scale":"1","size":"500"}
},
{
    "name":"Second",
    "id":"1",
    "data": {"scale":"2","size":"600"}
}]
```

Comment: The JSON is valid - it doesn't match the types that the OP is trying to deserialize to, but that's a problem with those deserialization classes. Note that the OP isn't in control (as far as we can see) of the JSON - but they *are* in control of the classes they're using.

Comment: Understood. We can also create a custom JSON converter. Will that work?